# How to get version for a plugin inside Vim?

Tags: vim, plugins

Is it possible to get the version number for an installed plugin from within Vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in general: no. there is no concept of `plugin-version` in vim. if the plugin itself provides some variable, you might `:echo` that one.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get the version number for an installed plugin from within Vim?

Yes, as long as the plugin installs from github.

One example... let's find the version of the `vim` Plugin called [`ale`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/)...

- First, `cd` into your plugin's git root directory... in my case, it's `cd /home/mpenning/.vim/bundle/ale`.
- `git log | grep commit | head -n1`.  This returns: `commit 607f33a1b0f662d9809d54363e8e81a4965862ce`
- Now I go to the [github list of `ale` commits](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/commits/master).  Remember to account for the fact that github shows a short hash and `git log` gives you a long hash.

The [hash matched `git HEAD`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/commit/607f33a1b0f662d9809d54363e8e81a4965862ce)... based on the [`git tag` list](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/tags), the most recent version of [`ale`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/) is version 3.2.0.

So I'm running `ale` git HEAD... just north of [`ale`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/) version [3.2.0](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/commit/560e6340ce10ce90fac587096fb147eea43e624d)

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins lists the version in the help files. E.g. with `Nvim-R`, you can see the version using `:help nvim-r`.